# How to programatically install Chromium extension/userscript?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium, userscripts

I have a need to automate the installation of scripts in Chromium. I've created a Windows shell replacement which allows me to open multiple unique Chromium sessions and place them in kiosk mode on whichever monitor I specify. My problem is that I'm using some userscripts/tampermonkey scripts to automate certain things for some dashboards in the kiosk.

I'm thinking of replacing the tampermonkey scripts with normal userscripts. I've tested adding a script by dragging and dropping into extensions and then later editing the file directly for updates and this works fine. My question is, how could I programatically or automatically install **new** userscripts into Chromium?

Sorry for the lack of code examples or anything like that but this question doesn't really have anything to show. Oh, and I can't really do the pre-installed extensions through `registry/GPO` or `master_preferences`.

Comment: Not sure how you plan to install something without the methods to install it.  From where did you plan on installing the extensions?

Comment: You can emulate drag'n'drop with AutoHotkey.

Comment: @Brad I was hoping to be able to use a DLL from Chromium that might have an exported function to install an extension or code the process myself through copying files and editing the Chromium extension database/preference file from my code.